# Importing text only out of string field to new field for labelling in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, labeling, python-parser

I want to import data out of a string field in my shapefile to a new field for labeling.

The string field contains river names and codes and I just want to display the text i.e river names

Comment: could you post an example of the river names and codes?

Answer (score 1):

In field calculator you can use this python function under the Show Codeblock option:

```
def removeNumbers(oldfield, newfield):
  newfield = ''.join([letter for letter in oldfield if not letter.isdigit()])
  return newfield
```

---

```
removeNumbers(!StringNumber!, !NoNumber!)
```

Answer (score 0):

This question, and its [first answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/29874), appear to have been written at a time prior to the [Python Parser becoming available for writing Label Expressions](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/working-with-text/about-building-label-expressions.htm).

In this case I think the expression (untested) would be:

```
def FindLabel ( [StringNumber] ):
  S = ''.join([letter for letter in [StringNumber] if not letter.isdigit()])
  return S
```